# How to display overline above a fraction?

Tags: texmaker, fractions, bar

I'd like to add a bar / overline above a fractional statement, such as the one in this image:
[image: overline above the fraction z/w]

I am using `tasks` package and this inside a `\subparagraph` inside a `\paragraph`.I have tried in some manners:

- `\task $\overline{\(\frac{z}{w}\)}$`
- `\task $\overline{$\(\frac{z}{w}\$)}$`
- `\task $\overline{\(\displaystyle \frac{z}{w}\)}$`

And a few other combinations as well as with `\bar`. Error messages usually consist of:

- *Extra }, or forgotten $...*
- *Bad math environment delimiter...*

Edit: Solution was to use different notation to `\[ ... \]` like this:

`$\overline{(\frac{z}{w})}$`

Comment: Seems the problem is, that you use `\( .... \)`

Comment: Try `$\overline{\left(\frac{w}{z}\right)}$` or `$\displaystyle \overline{\left(\frac{w}{z}\right)}$`

Comment: @cis Yup, seems like you were correct. the \(...\) notation doesn't combine with the $$...$$ form and additionally I'm not utilizing the `amsmath` package either.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.